# global gitconfig file unreachable in Sublime Text

Tags: git, sublimetext, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sublimetext4

I'm learning Git and currently trying to configure it on **WSL(v2) - Ubuntu 20.04** on Windows 10. When I execute commands like

```
git config --global user.name "XX YYY"
```

It works fine. I set my code editor to Sublime Text (v4) which is NOT installed on WSL, but on Windows. I invoke it using `subl.exe --wait` and *subl.exe* is in `PATH`. When I use *subl* to edit files from WSL, with `subl.exe xyz.txt`, everything works and the location is displayed correctly. But I cannot open the *.gitconfig* file (which is of course, located at WSL home). So when I execute

```
git config --global -e
```

to edit the *.gitconfig* file directly, Sublime Text *opens* and informs me that the path `\\\home\<username>\.gitconfig` has become unreachable. I know that in WSL2 the Linux home is mounted at a network location, and maybe this is causing the problem. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is permissions on the config file. There should be "config" file at /home/username/.git  directory.
If so make sure you have the correct permissions on that file

Comment: @KausUntwale The `.gitconfig` file has the permissions **-rw-r--r--**. Which means it's atleast readable for any user, and even if I can't edit it in ST4, I should be able to just open it up, right?

Comment: yeah thats right, sorry couldnt be of any help. I have windows and red hat running on the same machine, when i create a txt file on linux i have to chmod it in order to edit in windows. So thought that was your issue. Make sure your home and home/user directories have +x for all users as well.